# PrimeFaces HotKey with ImageSwitch

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, hotkeys

I use PrimeFaces HotKey component for changing image with right and left keys.But it isnot working as the example on the PrimeFaces site.The image is not changing.What is the reason or what is missing in the codes.Here are the codes.

```
<p:imageSwitch effect="fade" widgetVar="switcher">
     <p:graphicImage value="/images/k1.jpg"/>
     <p:graphicImage value="/images/k2.jpg"/>
     <p:graphicImage value="/images/k3.jpg"/>
     <p:graphicImage value="/images/k4.jpg"/>
</p:imageSwitch>
<p:hotkey bind="left" handler="PF('switcher').previous();" />  
<p:hotkey bind="right" handler="PF('switcher').next();" />
```

Comment: I couldn't replicate the error. Have you seen anything wrong like "ReferenceError: PF is not defined" on your firebug console?

Comment: No I didn't get an error.It is not changing the image.